# ARM assembly program would not store the result in register 0

Tags: arm

I need to write a ARM assembly program will “iteratively” sum up (the integer multiplication of each integer element in the array_D by 4) and also the next element by looping until the end of the array signaled by 0. In each iteration, the current element x of the array_D will be replaced with the new result of summation as (x * 4 + [next element]). For instance, in case array_D = [2020, -97, 2441, -11, 0], the final result stored in r0 should be : (2020 * 4 - 97) + (-97 * 4 + 2441) + (2441 * 4 -11) + (-11 * 4 + 0)= 19745, with the array_D updated as [7983, 2053, 9753, -44, 0]. When it reaches the end of the array, the ARM assembly program will exit the loop and then terminate the program execution with the result of summation stored in register r0. Here is the program I've written:

```
@ File : simple2.s------------------------
.data
array_D:  .word 2020, -97, 2441, -11, 0
.text 
.global main  
main:  

    LDR r1,=array_D     @ load base addr. of array_D into r1
    MOV r2, #0      @ r2 as the array pointer
loop:
    LDR r3, [r1,r2]     @ r3 as the array element
    LSL r3, r3, #2      @ multiply r3 by 4
    MOV r4, r2      @ copy r2 to r4
    ADD r2, r2, #4      @ r2 points to next element
    LDR r5, [r1,r2]     @ r5 as the next element
    ADD r3, r3, r5      @ add r5 to r3
    ADD r0, r0, r3      @ sum the new element to r0 (change this to ADD r6, r6, 
r3 and it worked)
    STR r3, [r1,r4]     @ store the new value to the array_D
    CMP r5, #0      @ test if the next element is 0
    BNE loop        @ loop if not 0

SWI 0x11
.end
```

However this program will not store the final result in r0 but zero instead (register view 1). I have tried r6 to store the result and it worked (register view 2). But the assignment requires me to store it in r0. What is wrong with my program?

[register view 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUCqp.png)

[register view 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbWTI.png)

Comment: I don't see where you ever initialized `r0`, so it starts out containing garbage which you then add to.  I don't know if that's your bug, but it certainly doesn't seem right.

Comment: If you replace your program with something completely trivial, e.g. `mov r0, #123`, does it work?  If not, there may be something wrong with your emulator.

Comment: If I don't use loop and just add something to r0 directly, it does show the result.